# v-model with dynamic input from computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

So I had a use case when I need to generate the dynamic form in a website. I'm using `v-for` to iterate on my form and `v-model` on computed properties, on Vue docs it is stated that using `get()` or `set()` are the way to go, but I got an error message

```
[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

Here my code :

store.js

```js
function dynamic() {
  return {
    ini: 12
  };
}

export const state = () => ({
  message: []
});

export const mutations = {
  setMessage(state, value) {
    console.log(value);
    state.message = value;
  },
  setDynamic(state, value) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      arr.push(dynamic());
    }
    state.message = arr;
  }
};
```

component.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in message" :key="index">
      <input placeholder="Hallo V-Model" v-model="message[index].ini">
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    message: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.messages.message;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("messages/setMessage", value);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      dynamic: "messages/setDynamic"
    })
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.dynamic();
  }
};
</script>
```

More interactive one can be found here at my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-e8tb7) do you had any idea why it throw error? and how to fix this issue?

## Update

Manage to fix it with set 'strich mode' to false, but still, I don't know where I mutate the state outside of mutation. Answer still needed

Comment: post your whole code please, where are you import vuex libs?

Comment: I post my full code mate, and I also gave the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-e8tb7)

Comment: your code not executes for me.

Comment: Just open the codesandbox, its more easy if you want to test it. If not then create a nuxt app and replace the component and your store with my code.

Comment: Yes, I understanded, but how I edit it?

Comment: You could just edit and play with it mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [vuex-maps-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields) as a shortcut, they provide higher level `get()` and `set()` whitin vuejs so you can use `v-model with them`

I mutated the object on `messages` so I need to clone it before applying new value. Here how the library does that so It wont mutate your state outside `mutations` https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields/blob/8ce9a2751be7996214c0c68c25afa2f2ef5b7446/src/index.js#L61